# Microsoft.Typescript was not imported by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS Community Studio 2019 to build a new web page with ASP.NET. Upon creating new RESTful API templates, I receive this kind of error:

```
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" was not imported by "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.ProjectSystem.targets" at (14,3), due to the file being invalid
```

It is also an issue for Microsoft.Typescript.Default.props and Microsoft.TypeScript.DotNetCore.targets, leading to an error (I guess)  :`Root element is missing`. 
Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same error in my case this worked :

1 - Go to NuGet packages manager
2 - Install this package : Microsoft.TypesCript.MSBuild

Regards

Comment: after 2 and a half years, it finally works

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the TypeScript SDK, the error became an warning: `"This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored."`